# Curl Command Line to Logout of Github Enterprise

Tags: curl, github-api

Is there a way to logout of github enterprise using curl command line?. I found that you can do the same with JIRA.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Automating+JIRA+operations+via+wget

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way of doing that with JIRA and there's no way to "logout" of GitHub's API (enterprise or otherwise) because each request is idempotent. Your authentication is not based on a session with cookies but rather by sending information each time to authenticate yourself. It looks as though the same is true for JIRA.

Comment: I could find how to logout of JIRA by using it's api.  

curl -b cookies-#{@system['product']}.txt -c cookies-#{@system['product']}.txt -X DELETE "http://jira.nreca.org/rest/auth/latest/session" --head --silent

Comment: Well it isn't documented and the old adage is that if it isn't document it doesn't exist. The next update to JIRA could cause it to entirely disappear. Regardless, my answer stands that since GitHub doesn't use cookies there is no need to log out of GitHub.

Comment: I guess i will a different approach to login to these applications to make sure they are up and running

Comment: With GitHub enterprise, I am not aware (then again I don't work on it or for GitHub) that their Enterprise API and their product run on different servers (in fact I'd be surprised if they did). As such, you can probably authenticate as the admin and hit some of the enterprise-only API endpoints. I forget where the docs for those are though.